# Integration of a font layout engine in kivy?

Tags: python-3.x, kivy

I want to integrate a font layout engine in kivy module, how should I do it? 
I have learnt kivy recently and want to try an open source project.

Comment: what did you try so far?

Comment: I read about Pango and came to know that it has been integrated in many Linux distributions. What can be the best way to start a project to integrate such libraries in kivy?

Comment: Ok. You want to use pango to make some text on a png and display it in kivy? Or how do you want to use it for example?